# shapes not compatible issue when running optimizer step in tensorflow image segmentation

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am performing an image segmentation task in tensorflow.

Code:

```
height = 1024
width = 1024
channels = 1

# input place holders
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, channels], name = 'image')

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, channels], name = 'annotation')

# variable learning rate
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'lr')




W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 2], stddev=0.1)) 
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2])/(2*2))

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 2, 1], stddev=0.1)) 
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1])/(1*1))

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2, 1, 1], stddev=0.1)) 
B3 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1])/(1*1))




stride = 1  
Y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, W1, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding= 'VALID') + B1)

stride = 1  
Y2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(Y1, W2, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='VALID') + B2)

Ylogits = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(Y2, W3, output_shape = [1, 1024, 1024, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1])
```

Everything is good except when I run this line :

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cross_entropy_sum)

Traceback:

train_step = 
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cross_entropy_sum)

```
File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 580, in gradients
    in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
  File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 413, in set_shape
    self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
  File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 564, in merge_with
    (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (1, 512, 512, 1) and (?, 1020, 1020, 1) are not compatible
```

Comment: change your logits to [1, 512, 512,1]

Comment: Could you explain me why? I want my output to be same size as my input i.e., 1024x1024x1

Comment: The error is because the output shape is not same as input. If your input shape is 1024x1024x1, then what is (1, 512, 512,1) ?

Comment: (1,512,512,1) is the output of conv2d layers after applying convolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the strides on your `conv2d_transpose` operation are `[1, 2, 2, 1]`, it will result in an output with twice the height and width of the input. See [this Data Science answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) and the [page it links here](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) for visualizations of why this happens.

You set your `output_shape = [1, 1024, 1024, 1]`, and the deconvolutional layer expects half the height and width as input, and the same batch size and number of channels, which means it expects a shape of [1, 512, 512, 1].

The input you gave it, Y2, is of shape [None, 1020, 1020, 1], because the two `conv2d` layers each trim off a little around the edges of your data, but because the stride is one, they do not significantly decrease the width or height. The batch size is None because it stays the same through those layers.

To fix this, one option is to use a stride of [1, 2, 2, 1] on one of your convolutional layers, which will roughly halve the width and height (To exactly halve them, use `padding='SAME'`. This will prevent the edges from being slightly trimmed). You'll also have to change the `output_shape` of the deconvolutional layer to [None, 1024, 1024, 1].

Comment: This may solve my problem, but what should I do if wanted to have the exact numbers 1024x1024x1 instead of rough ones? If I give the stride of 2 to one of my convolution also, the output is not is equal to 512(half of my output)

Comment: (I didn't originally put this in my answer because I wasn't aware of it until now) In your convolutional layers, if you change `padding='SAME'`, it will prevent the edges from being trimmed. If you use that in conjunction with a stride of 2, your height and width will be exactly halved.

Comment: That problem is resolved if I remove the convolution layer with stride 1. Thanks though!